# how to tell app to stop processing after exception is thrown

Tags: c#, mysql

My application is set up to connect to a MySQL database. Which it does fine when it's online.
My query is when it's offline, Visual studio throws an exception even after showing me the "Cannot connect to a database" exception message in a message box.

I put the connection parameters in their own class. Most declarations have been made under the public class declarations.

```
// Command to open connection to database
    public bool OpenCon()
    {

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
            //I was hoping to get the application to stop processing further after it failed to connect here.
        }

    }

    // Command to close connection to database
    public bool CloseCon()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;

        }

    }

    // This method is triggered by the 'signup_Click' event in the signup window
    public void Join(signup Signup)
    {
        // We now have the existing login window as "Signup".

        //Query to excecute
        query = "insert into temp.signup (member, first, second, third, surname, sex, ......) values ('" + Signup.member.Text + "', '" + Signup.first.Text + "','" + Signup.second.Text + "','" + Signup.third.Text + "','" + Signup.surname.Text + "', '" + Signup.sex.Text + "',....... );";
        //Declarations
        MySqlDataReader rdr;
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);



        // Excecution
        try
        {
            //Open the connection
            OpenCon();

            //Excecute the command
            //This is where the exception is thrown when the computer is offline, by the data reader.
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //Show the confirmation message
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Saved");

            //CLose the connection
            CloseCon();
        }
        //If this fails, catch the exception
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //And show it in a messagebox
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            CloseCon();
        }
    }
```

I'm obviously wrong as this is happening but I was under the impression that processing stops after you've used the return key word to exit the method, or it was by default when an exception is thrown.

So my question is how do I tell it to stop from going any further if the 'OpenCon' method returns false (Fails to connect to the database)?

I would prefer it to not throw a second exception that pauses my app and simply wait for further instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
if(OpenCon())
{
            //Excecute the command
            //This is where the exception is thrown when the computer is offline, by the data reader.
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //Show the confirmation message
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Saved");

            //CLose the connection
            CloseCon();
}
```

good that you have a bool return value, check for it and take further action.

Answer (score 0):

Application is not terminated if exception is thrown. In layman's term an application is forcefully terminated by CLR if an exception is not caught anywhere in the application. Since you have handled the exception and not re-thrown it, CLR assumes that you have "handled" the exception and proceeds forward with execution of rest of the code.

I assume you want to forcefully terminate the application in the catch block. This is very bad practise and beats the whole purpose of exception handling. You should gracefully notify the user and proceed with the alternate scenario. 
But for the sake of your knowledge you can use `Environment.FailFast` to forcefully exit the application IMMEDIATELY. This is highly discouraged as it terminates the application NOW without even executing any of the finally block and should be avoided unless it is a catastrophic failure.

Better throw a custom exception and let it bubble up so that you can catch it safely in UI layer notify the user.